# Как удалить нижний отступ у div

Tags: css

Как удалить нижний отступ у browser__header, чтобы он был присоединен к pre.code?

```html
<div class="code__block">
  <div class="browser__header">
    <div class="browser__button"></div>
    <div class="browser__button"></div>
    <div class="browser__button"></div>
  </div>
  <pre class="code">
    text
    </pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

style="margin-bottom:0px";

В бутстраппе:
class="mb-0"

Comment: Спасибо большое